# How to run command before data.archive_file zips folder in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I try to implement aws lambda function using terraform.

I simply have `null_resource` that have local provisioner and `resource.archive_file` that zips source code after all preparation is done.

```
resource "null_resource" "deps" {

  triggers = {
    package_json = "${base64sha256(file("${path.module}/src/package.json"))}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "cd ${path.module}/src && npm install"
  }
}

resource "archive_file" "function" {
    type = "zip"
    source_dir = "${path.module}/src"
    output_path = "${path.module}/function.zip"

    depends_on = [ "null_resource.deps" ]
}
```

Recent changes to Terraform deprecated `resource.archive_file`, so `data.archive_file` should be used instead. Unfortunately, `data` executes before resources, and so local provisioner from dependent resource is called way after zip is created. So code bellow does not produce warning any more, however not working at all.

```
resource "null_resource" "deps" {

  triggers = {
    package_json = "${base64sha256(file("${path.module}/src/package.json"))}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "cd ${path.module}/src && npm install"
  }
}

data "archive_file" "function" {
    type = "zip"
    source_dir = "${path.module}/src"
    output_path = "${path.module}/function.zip"

    depends_on = [ "null_resource.deps" ]
}
```

Am I missing something? What is correct way to do this with recent versions.

Terraform: v0.7.11
OS: Win10

Comment: I think you are right, and it is not possible to do using just Terraform.

Comment: The example in the question works fine for me. You can use the `working_dir` option instead of prefixing it with `cd`.

Answer (score 15):

Turns out there is an issue with the way Terraform core handles `depends_on` for data resources. There are a couple of issues reported, one in the [archive provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-archive/issues/11) and another in [the core](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17034).

The following workaround is listed in the archive provider issue. Note that it uses a `data.null_data_source` to sit between the `null_resource` and `data.archive_file` which makes it an explicit dependency as opposed to an implicit dependency with `depends_on`.

```
resource "null_resource" "lambda_exporter" {
  # (some local-exec provisioner blocks, presumably...)

  triggers = {
    index = "${base64sha256(file("${path.module}/lambda-files/index.js"))}"
  }
}

data "null_data_source" "wait_for_lambda_exporter" {
  inputs = {
    # This ensures that this data resource will not be evaluated until
    # after the null_resource has been created.
    lambda_exporter_id = "${null_resource.lambda_exporter.id}"

    # This value gives us something to implicitly depend on
    # in the archive_file below.
    source_dir = "${path.module}/lambda-files/"
  }
}

data "archive_file" "lambda_exporter" {
  output_path = "${path.module}/lambda-files.zip"
  source_dir  = "${data.null_data_source.wait_for_lambda_exporter.outputs["source_dir"]}"
  type        = "zip"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is much more graceful than some of the previous ideas I've read, and solves a problem I had where the archive was marked as changed on every run.

Comment: This makes writing go lambdas with terraform so much better. Thanks!

Comment: I end up with precisely the same error by implementing this method. I still get `Error: error archiving directory: could not archive missing directory` even though the archive's source is the null_data_source's source_dir. It still doesn't trigget the null_resource. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new data source in Terraform 0.8, `external` that allows you to run external commands and extract output.   See [`data.external`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/index.html)

The data source should **only** be used for the retrieval of some depedency value, not the execution of the `npm install`, you should still do that via the `null_resource`.  Since this is a Terraform data source, it should not have any side effects (although you may need some in this case, not sure).

So basically, `null_resource` does the dependencies, `data.external` grabs some value that you can depend on for the archive (directory path for example), then `data.archive_file` performs the archiving.

This would probably work best with a pseudo random directory name potentially to make dirty checks work a little cleaner.

Comment: I'd really appreciate a sample of this chain of dependencies based on the original. I am getting started and just find this very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another working example that doesn't use the 'null_data_source' solution. This work around combines everything into the null_resource block as I was still facing issues with the provided solution.

```
resource "null_resource" "dependancies" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = <<EOT
      mkdir script-files
      cp import.py script-files
      pip3 install requests --target script-files
      cd script-files
      chmod -R 644 $(find . -type f)
      chmod -R 755 $(find . -type d)
      zip -r ../lambda_function.zip *
    EOT
    working_dir = path.module
  }
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}
```